# Use fingerprint login without pin

Tags: windows-10, login, fingerprint, pin

At the Windows 10 (21H1 build 19043.1266) login, I select fingerprint login.  I touch the fingerprint reader and the login prompt says "Your pin is required to sign in".  How do I change the login requirements to allow for only the fingerprint?

The enabled sign-in options are: Windows Hello Face, Windows Hello Fingerprint, Windows Hello PIN and Password enabled.

Note: I was able to login in with my fingerprint only about a week ago.  I recently installed [Workspace One Intelligent Hub](https://getwsone.com/) and this caused the problem.  I uninstalled the software and it did not revert the settings.

Comment: “Some software I installed changed this” - What software exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound I improved the question.

Comment: Workplace One is a utility suite meant for managing computers in an organization. It applies system policies. First, why did you install this? Does this computer belong to your employer, or do you own the computer but use it to work for someone else? The policies the software applied are what has caused this change, and so you'll need to find what these were in order to revert them. Have you gone through the policies governing this system behavior?

Comment: @music2myear I own the computer and my work offered the software.  I thought this would be helpful software.  Sigh.  How do I figure out the policies the software applies?

Comment: Your work offered the software? Have you asked them the policies it applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I did.  Some of the steps may not be necessary.

1. Open Settings
2. Click on `Accounts`
3. Click on `Sign-in options`
4. Click on `Windows Hello PIN`
5. Click on `Remove`.  (This removed my fingerprint and face recognition).
6. Click on `Password`
7. Click on `Change`
8. Click on `Fingerprint recognition`
9. Click on `Set up`.  (This had me setup a PIN)